# ropsten: insufficient funds for gas * price + value using web3

Tags: gas, ropsten, raw-transaction

Im using `"web3": "^1.0.0-beta.37"`

And I want to understand How can I send rawTransaction

My code is:

```
const pk = 'xxxxxxx';
const rawTransaction = {
    "to": "0xa53709839ab6Da3ad9c1518Ed39a4a0fFCbA3684",
    "value": web3.utils.toWei('1', 'wei'),
    "gas": 2000000,
    "chainId": 3
};
let signedTx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(rawTransaction, pk).catch(console.dir);
let sendTx = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction).catch(console.error);
```

My account has 4Eth (on ropsten) and my httpProvider is ropsten (using infura)

but I get this error

> Error: Returned error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value

I follow:

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html?highlight=signTransaction#signtransaction

and then

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#eth-sendsignedtransaction

Comment: Most of the time when I receive that error it's due to not being fully synced with the chain. Make sure you're fully synchronized.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen thanks for reply, I don't have ropsten locally, I use infura to broadcast my TX. It's wrong ?

Comment: Oh, if you use Infura then it's synchronized. Another thing I noticed is that I'm unsure if `toWei` supports decimal numbers - just to be sure use only integers. Check details: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#towei

Comment: why `from` field is missing in your raw transaction?, Try adding it and run.

Comment: Shouldn't 21000 gas be enough for this type of transaction?

Comment: what type of transaction you are trying to send? i mean user to contract or user to user ?

Comment: @goodvibration even with 2100 I have the same probelm

Comment: @MaheshRajput user to user

Comment: @Lauri Peltonen I updated my quesiton

Comment: @A.K.there isn't `form`, because the originator's public key can be computed directly from ECDSA signature, it's calling `public key recovery`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@abed Thanks for your reply and your suggests, the problem is PK, I have to add 0x before my PK that I get form Metamask

https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1094

Comment: awesome. This saves my life!

Answer (score 3):

Well, the message is saying that you don’t have funds. Here’s what you can do:

1. Double check that the pk you are using to sign that transaction is actually the private key of the account with enough balance.
2. Double check the web3 provider is actually pointing to the same network you have ethers in. Are you sure the infura node is connected to ropsten?
3. Try to execute getBalance() for that account and verify the output is displaying correctly your balance

Comment: 1. Im sure, Can I verify the integrity of signature ?
2. yes, the url is https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/API_KEY
3. await web3.eth.getBalance(address) => 12285448249427863490

Comment: Add a ‘from’ parameter to the transaction object with value your address

Comment: I try but not lucky

Comment: Then the problem is probably from the private key that you are using, I think it’s not correct

Comment: same address with sendTransaction works

Comment: I get PK from metamask

Answer (score 0):

`nonce`, `gasPrice` and `gasLimit` must be in hex.